# Is it possible with Photoshop to have hard corners rather than rounded corners?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am trying to achive this following look

[image]

If I use the rectangle and change the corner's pixels, it's rounded like so:

[image]

Is it possible to have flat corners, rather than rounded corners, if so how can I achieve that? thanks

Comment: Do it with 2 stages. First as you are and then "chop off" the curves

Answer (score 0):

draw the rectangle with the curved corners as you describe, then select the "Convert Point Tool" and click on each of the dark square points in turn. This will remove the "curve handle" and make the angles sharp.